# Can I change the target for the Start button Windows Explorer option?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, start-menu

I changed the target for my desktop Explorer shortcut but have not found a way to change it for the start button (RC) Windows Explorer. I'm assuming it would have to be a registry tweak but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Change it to what? What have you tried? Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified your Windows version.

However, normally one right-clicks on the Explorer entry, selects Properties, then changes the Shortcut details and OK.

If this is not working for you, could you please explain what is happening.

EDIT

From [Fix Windows Explorer in Windows 7, correctly pin it to the taskbar](http://www.osattack.com/windows-7/fix-windows-explorer-in-windows-7-correctly-pin-it-to-the-taskbar/) :

> Today’s solution is a much better way
>   to make Explorer be pinned to the
>   taskbar. It maintains the
>   functionality of Libraries and makes
>   Explorer function correctly.
>
> 1. Open the Start menu
> 2. Navigate to All Programs -> Accessories
> 3. Right click on Windows Explorer and select Properties
> 4. In the “Target” enter :
>    `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`
> 5. Select OK
>
> If you have previously pinned
>   Libraries or Windows Explorer to your
>   taskbar you will need to Unpin and
>   then Pin it again to make the changes
>   active. After it is pinned, when you
>   click on the Windows Explorer folder
>   in your taskbar it will open to
>   Computer.

Comment: Version win7 HP. I wish to change it to open at C: not at Libraries. Properties does not allow to change the target for explorer. It opens taskbar and start menu props. I have changed the regular explorer icon on the desktop but can't seem to change the start menu explorer drop down to what I wish.

Comment: when I right click the explorer submenu I am taken directly to explorer libraries. No way to change the target. Again I assume it is a registry hack that must be done. I cannot find it on microsoft, HTG, Daniels, Paul Thurrott, No where. Kinda lost. Hasn't anyone wished to do this or am not searching appropriately? Thanks in advance

Comment: My edit above may help.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Wait, that wasn't the question. Nevermind.

Assuming you're on Windows 7 (I wouldn't know in which other version that specific problem might arise):

Yes, you can. Just right click on the "Windows Explorer" entry that pops up when you right-click the taskbar icon (please don't mind the button descriptors, "Eigenschaften" is "Preferences"):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the command-line options `/e` and `/root` (create a shortcut)

To open with c drive as root:

`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e /root, c:`

Or, to open with 'my computer' as root:

`%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /e /root, ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`

For more information, see:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853

some useful guid's:

Explorer
{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}

Control Panel
{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}

Internet Explorer
{FBF23B42-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}

My Documents
{ECF03A32-103D-11d2-854D-006008059367}

Fonts
{BD84B380-8CA2-1069-AB1D-08000948F534}

My Computer
{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}

My Network Places
{208D2C60-3AEA-1069-A2D7-08002B30309D}

Network Connections
{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}

Printers and Faxes
{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}

Recycle Bin
{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}

Scheduled Tasks
{D6277990-4C6A-11CF-8D87-00AA0060F5BF}